# Windows equivalent for ip route show cache

Tags: windows

What is the Windows equivalent for

```
ip route show cache
```

or

```
ip route show 172.16.225.53 table cache
```

On linux it shows cached route for the host:

```
172.16.225.53 from 172.19.55.150 dev tun0 
cache  ipid 0x3cff rtt 242ms rttvar 55ms ssthresh 35 cwnd 29 reordering 10 initrwnd 10
```

I would like to find out what ssthresh and cwnd parameters is Windows internally using for my connection, because I could not get over 16384 bytes in flight on a long fat network.

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
route print
```

What you need? As a Windows user, I have no idea what your example does.

Comment: man page says it does this, "cached list cloned routes i.e. routes which were dynamically forked from other routes because some route  attribute  (f.e.  MTU)  was updated."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but route print does not provide the info I am looking for. I have added more details to my question.